# Code readability with c++11 lambdas

Tags: c++, coding-style, lambda, c++11

I REALLY love lambdas and having the ability to use them in C++ is a pleasure. But, as I'm used to Haskell, where lambdas fit really well into the syntax, I'm struggling with how to use them in C++ without writing unreadable cluttered long code lines.

So, as an example, suppose I'd write this:

```
vector<double> foo(10,0.2);
for_each(foo.begin(), foo.end(), [](double x){ std::cout << x << " ";})
```

this is not so difficult to read, the lambda expression is pretty small. But if I have a two or three line long function inside that for_each, this could become a problem for my 
code-reading-skills:

```
vector<double> foo(10,0.2);
randomNumberGenerator bar;
for_each(foo.begin(), foo.end(), [](double x){ std::cout << "hello!"; x+=bar()/(1+bar()); std::cout << x << " ";})
//sorry, I couldn't think of a less stupid example...
```

This line is starting to get annoyingly long and difficult to read for my taste...

What is your preferred code conventions for this case? Should I write:

```
for_each(foo.begin(), foo.end(), 
          [] (double x) {
                std::cout << "hello!"
                x += bar()/(1+bar());
                std::cout << x << " ";
          });
```

or something like it? I still think this syntax feels a bit unnatural and difficult to read... :(

Comment: I like the last option, except that you place the opening brace incorrectly. :-)

Comment: why is this not "subjective and argumentative"?

Comment: If you want it shorter, also use boost range which takes the container only as first argument. (boost::for_each(foo, [](){...});)

Comment: Interestingly, this is exactly what I did in [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23418114/multiplication-table-with-one-line-of-code) hoping for better readability.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I usually go for

```
for_each(foo.begin(), foo.end(), [](double x) {
    std::cout << "hello!"
    x += bar()/(1+bar());
    std::cout << x << " ";
});
```

I've written some several hundred line lambdas.

Comment: +1: I haven't yet written many lambdas, but from reading them when learning about them the often look like the body of a loop or other block.  In those situations, having the lambda code inline is as natural as having your loop code inline.  I think you should use the same reasons for moving lambda contents out-of-line (or not moving the contents out-of-line) as you'd use for other loop bodies.

Answer (score 6):

If you prefer, you can name your lambda separately with `auto`:

```
auto const baz = [](double x)
{
    std::cout << "hello!"
    x += bar()/(1+bar());
    std::cout << x << " ";
};
std::for_each(foo.begin(), foo.end(), baz);
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the `const` in `auto const` for your lambda declaration?

Comment: @Phlucious : I have a "const wherever possible" mentality, so habit I suppose. It's certainly not necessary for a lambda, no hidden surprises here. :-]

Answer (score 4):

Hmm...

```
for_each(foo.begin(), foo.end(), 
    [] (double x)
    {
        std::cout << "hello!"
        x += bar()/(1+bar());
        std::cout << x << " ";
    });

for (auto x : foo)
{
    std::cout << "hello!";
    x += bar()/(1+bar());
    std::cout << x << " ";
}
```

Comment: Maybe an algorithm other than `for_each` would have made for a better example here, but the for loop here is much more natural to me.

Answer (score 2):

I like to look at lambdas as just another function declaration, and thus, follow the same conventions that I use for other functions, within reason:

```
// when lambdas are present, I break the enveloping method params
for_each(
  foo.begin(), 
  foo.end(),           
  [] (double x)
  // I also like to split the brackets, just like with any function
  {
     std::cout << "hello!" 
     x += bar()/(1+bar());                
    std::cout << x << " ";          
  }); // the closing parenthesis is left with the closing bracket
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say if the code for the lambda is more than one or perhaps two statements, it should be  a separate named function.

Comment: IMO, that should only be necessary if you intend to re-use the code elsewhere.

Comment: IMO, it is necessary if you want the code to be readable, understandable and testable

Comment: A named lambda is less readable than a named function? That's about as subjective as it gets.

Comment: @ildjarn  Did I say that? Oh look, I didn't! I said a named function was more readable than a lambda. Most people would take that to mean an unnamed one. But in any case, yes. I believe that named functions are clearer than named lambdas, and I suspect 99% of C++ programmers would be with me on this. Sigh. We have lived through the horrors of template misuse - I suppose we must now go through it again with lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

Post mine

```
std::vector<int> a;
std::find_if(a.begin()
           , a.end()
           , [&](int i)
             {
                 return i == 0;
             });
```